# Validate microsoft Excel data cell in Java

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, import-from-excel

How to validate excel's column in Java spring? Validation such as column should be string or not null. After read Excel file, do validation then all data will be store in database's table.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to that is: you, probably, have to use the JXL library (or something similar). It allows you to access concrete cells in Excel sheets and get their values (amongst other things).

Comment: hi lbolit, i have use jxl library and can read data from excel sheet, but no idea for do validation as i don't have model class

Comment: I am sorry, I do not quite understand you. If you know that your value should be a string or null, then you can just check if that value is a string or null. What do you mean by Model class?

Comment: sorry about model class. Let say the excel file have twenty column ,first column is String ,second is int, third is date, fourth is String, fifth is int........ I read through all data in excel file using looping. I have no idea about validation when i read data which String data should go to either column one or four ....

Comment: Well, if you can't distinguish between different sorts of strings (by, for example, their length, charset, regular expressions etc), then there is, probably, no difference as to which column they should be in? Again, if i understand you correctly, you have an excel file that you read, and you have to make sure that all the values are in their respective columns? or that all the values correspond to the _type_ of the columns?

Comment: all the values correspond to the type of columns